# Nuclear shadowing effect

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I am reading some texts which mention the nuclear shadowing effect (NSE). However, they don't explain explicitly what is NSE. So my questions are as follows:

1. What is the NSE?
2. What is its origin?

Comment: Can you tell us the title and author of the book?  I have never heard of this either, despite having a degree in physics, and despite having taught the subject many times.  Nor can I find much on the web about it.  If you give us this information, it may shed enough light for me to at least direct you to an explanation.

Comment: [Recent uses of the phrase on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+EXACT+nuclear%5fshadowing/0/1/0/all/0/1) suggest it's a medium modification, especially in RHIC experiments. I look forward to a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression of cross section for lepton-nucleon collision has term specifying the finite extent of charge distribution of nucleon.

When expressed in terms of lorentz invariant kinematic variables like x and $Q^2$, this term is referred to as 'Structure Function, $F_2$'. This is an experimentally measurable quantity. We measure it for nucleon as well as nuclei collision with lepton (say, electron).

We have a very good model to find various parameters(e.g. cross section, number of participating nucleons etc) of nucleus-nucleus(AA) collision called as Glauber Model.

The basic assumption of this model is that AA collisions could be build up from nucleon-nucleon(pp) collisions. If this is to be true, we expect that

$Nuclear\; Ratio, R= \frac{{F_2}^{nuclei}/A}{{F_2}^{nucleon}}=1 $

where A is mass number of nuclei and ${F_2}^{nuclei}$ and ${F_2}^{nucleon}$ are experimentally measured values of structure functions of nuclei and nucleons respectively.

But we find out that Nuclear Ratio, R is not 1, but varies with x for a constant $Q^2$ as follows

[image: Nuclear Ratio as a function of x]

For low x values, it implies that we get lower lepton-nuclei collision cross section than what we would have expected from scaled up lepton-nucleon collision cross section.

This is as if, the central nucleons of nuclei are being shielded due to surface nucleons. This is called **Shadowing Effect**.

Shadowing is caused by 'multiple scattering' of quark pair produced from the virtual photon emitted by the lepton. I do not understand this part well.

There are various models to explain shadowing:

- Vector meson dominance
- Parton recombination
- Glauber-like rescattering
- Gribov inelastic shadowing

References:

- Modern Particle Physics by Mark Thompson, Chapter on Deep inelastic Scattering (DIS)
- [Nuclear Shadowing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0604108.pdf)
- Nuclear Shadowing in a Parton Recombination Model by S. Kumano
- [Glauber Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-ex/0701025.pdf)